# Model Error estimation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, sampling, inference, error

Assume we have some credit model, which has calibrated (up to some error) score of how credit-worthy any individual person is.

For example, if the model’s estimate is 83% then we can assume the actual score is between 81% and 85%. If we take 83% as a score cutoff and deem everyone above that score as credit-worthy, are we over-estimating or underestimating the actual population’s credit score?

Answer (score 0):

This would largely depend on the model.
If you could create separate training and testing data sets you could use a number of regression methods to find evidence you are over/under/accurately estimating the population's credit score.

We don't currently have enough information about the model's accuracy or tendency to under/over predict. A graph of residuals would really help discern which way it is.